# Postagem inadequada removida, porém visível

Tags: debate

Postagem: [Como criar um <select> com imagens nas opções?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13188/como-criar-um-select-com-imagens-nas-op%C3%A7%C3%B5es/162361#162361)

Sinalizei essa postagem que está com status de "removida".
O motivo da sinalização é que apesar de removida continua visível para usuários com um determinado nível de pontos.

Para mim aparece dessa foma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A princípio achei desnecessário dar atenção e sinalizar mas por fim decidi sinalizar pois acho estranho manter algo assim, mesmo que esteja marcado como "removido".

A sinalização foi rejeitada.

O que acham disso? É útil manter esse conteúdo mesmo que com status de "removido"?

Para mim, não agrega em nada e poderia ser removido permanentemente ou ocultar por completo.

Comment: Tu tens reputação para ver esse tipo de conteúdo, é mesmo assim, é uma vantagem de alcançares 10k de reputação. A postagem na verdade encontra-se removida e eu, por exemplo, não a consigo ver.

Comment: Uma vez fiz uma pergunta parecida no metão e levei uma "shogada" :P -  http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/163446

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O sistema é assim, se deseja que mude deve solicitar um novo recurso. Portanto não tem o que fazer se o sistema não for mudado.

## Não há ganho

É útil manter isso para que as pessoas que são moderadores comunitários possa tomar alguma ação quando encontra esse tipo de conteúdo, é raro precisar, mas é útil.

Se está apagado não é indexado e o grosso das pessoas não o vê. Mesmo quem vê está bem indicado que é algo que foi removido e não deve ser considerado como conteúdo válido. Não não é questão de agregar alguma coisa ou não.

O site funciona como muitos banco de dados funcionam, pra que apagar algo que potencialmente pode ser reaproveitado? Que ganho teria nisso? E se apagar definitivo, o que fazer se precisar reaproveitar? Como reavaliar se foi apagado definitivamente?

Pode-se pensar: "deixa algumas coisas que podem ser úteis, apaga o que certamente não é útil". Mas alguém terá que julgar isso e poderá errar.

Ter essa remoção definitiva também não agrega nada, pelo contrário, desagrega já que ninguém mais poderá reavaliar aquilo, será bem difícil ocorrer mais alguma coisa ali. É mais ou menos porque muita gente é contra a pena de morte, não dá para voltar atrás se a decisão foi errada, sendo que decisões nos dois casos são tomadas com base nas escolha de apenas algumas pessoas, talvez uma, em determinado momento, muita coisa pode ter influenciado a decisão entre outras coisas que não vou me estender. No nosso caso ainda tem o fato de que a pessoa pode ter editado e querer que seja restaurado.

Então há menos ganho em remover isso do que deixar para moderadores comunitários enxergarem ele.

Em condições normais nem mesmo as pessoas com privilégios verão isso, já que essas coisas ficam esquecidas em um canto. O sistema é pragmático, não tem intenção de resolver cada pequeno detalhe que pode ou não ser o certo. Isso é tão raro que não vale o esforço de lidar com ele, e se lidar, o ganho será zero ou próximo disso.

## Exposição

Se era melhor deixar sem exposição, agora a exposição está grande. Esse era um caso que debater no meta amplifica o "problema" que se quer combater ao invés de resolvê-lo..

Comment: Pois é.. por isso sinalizei em privado para moderadores. Mas no feedback pedem para não sinalizar esses casos e postar no meta. Obrigado pela resposta de qualquer forma. Agora entendo melhor. Eu pensava que moderadores tinham mais permissões como remover por completo, por exemplo.

Comment: Cada caso é um caso, esse não foi dito para vir ao meta. Embora já tenha sido discutido o assunto entre os moderadores e não precisa ficar avisando o tempo todo para vir no meta em cada sinalização que não é caso para moderador analisar. Na maior parte dos casos o meta é melhor, poucas coisas devem ser tratadas privativamente. Só devem ser sinalizadas coisas que os moderadores podem fazer algo. Se fosse o caso poderia postar um pedido de novo recurso ou suporte e não debater esse post em específico. Os moderamos podem fazer bem poucas coisas a mais que a comunidade.

Comment: @bigown corrigi umas coisas, na última frase não sei se percebi bem o sentido, se vir que tal altere de novo ;)

Comment: Troquei a imagem para evitar expor tanto.

Comment: @bigown agora acho que há uma ferramenta para excluir o histórico de edições...

Comment: @JorgeB. isso não é uma edição. A ferramenta é pra esconder informações privadas, que nem é o caso, pelo menos ninguém reclamou disso, só porque tem um nome e uma foto não quer dizer que seja privado, isso costuma ser informação pública. E só pessoas com alta reputação pode ver se cair lá.

Comment: @bigown agora é.